# Adding a directory to the system path variable through registry

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, command-prompt

I am trying to add a directory to the `PATH` variable in windows. This is what I am entering the command line. (Or a batch file)

```
@echo off
set value=%path%;%ProgramFiles%\AtomScript\
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Sessions Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d %value% /f
```

And it comes up with this message

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "REG ADD /?" for usage.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have to quote `%value%` (with double-quotes) because its expansion has embedded blanks for `C:\Program Files`, etc.

That would be

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Sessions Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%value%" /f
```

You can see what the actual expansions are by turning `echo` on in your script:

```
@echo on
```

Comment: It spells `Session Manager` (singular Session) in my Window 2016 Data Center.

Comment: agreed, but that wouldn't answer OP's question about a syntax error.

Comment: It is `Session Manager` (singular Session) in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you solved it already, but as far as I can see you also might have a misspelling in "...\Sessions Manager...". At least on my system it's "Session" without the extra s.

Comment: The length and non-specificity of your answer indicates that it should be a comment instead.